# Use jquery timepicker and datepicker simultaneously

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, timepicker

I need to use both timepicker and datepicker. But only one of them works. My code is mentioned below. I am using multiple jquery files.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">



    $(document).ready(function() {




        $(".datepicker").datepicker({

            changeMonth: true,

            changeYear: true

        });



    });







    </script>








    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {



       $('.timepicker').timepicker({

                                        showPeriod: true,
                                        showLeadingZero: true

                                    });


    });



    </script>

     Date : <input type="text" class="datepicker"/>

     Time : <input type="text" class="timepicker"/>
```

Comment: can u make a fiddle .

Comment: @TusharGupta : http://jsfiddle.net/rKFN6/

Answer (score 1):

Check [Timepicker with Datepicker](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/) This one plugin has both pickers as a single component.

Comment: thanks a lot, i know about that but bound to use the current one :(

Answer (score 0):

I used https://github.com/trentrichardson/jQuery-Timepicker-Addon

```
<link href="yourpath/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.css'?>" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
<script src="yourpath/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js'?>"></script>
$(function() {
$( ".datepicker" ).datepicker();
});

$(function() {
$(".timepicker").timepicker();
});
```

and html
      input type="text" name="date" value="" placeholder="Conference Name" id="datepicker"

```
  input type="text" name="start_time" value="" placeholder="Starting Time" class="timepicker"

  input type="text" name="end_time" value="" placeholder="Ending Time" class="timepicker"
```

it works for me.I think its jquery version problem

Comment: which timepicker did u use?

Comment: please post the whole code along with html so that i can test it

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure the library is loaded from CDN http://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon
2. Once the js and CSS are loaded successfully, you can use the plugin as per examples given in httpp://jonthornton.github.io/jquery-timepicker/. I used the following options to get AM/PM selector;

   $('input.timepicker').timepicker({controlType: 'select',
                                               timeFormat: 'hh:mm TT',
                                               dropdown: true,
                                               scrollbar: false,
                                               ampm: true});
3. For detailed options list refer to httpp://timepicker.co/options/

2 links have httpp instead of http cz SO wouldn't allow me to post many links in one answer.